# How can I retrieve all custom elements, including those in shadowRoot, from a webpage in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, custom-element

I need to get array of custom elements in document using JS.

I tried to get all elements using querySelectorAll('*') and then filter elements by tag name, but it doesn't return elements in shadowRoot. ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ v‎  ‎  ‎        ‎ ‎  ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎  ‎ ‎

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76312666/shadow-root-watir-ruby/76316349#76316349

Answer (score -1):

Try using `const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("TagName here");`

That will give you all the elements in a array list by the specificated tag name.
`const element = document.getElementById("elementParent"); const elements = element.getElementsByTagName("TagName here")` that will give you the child elements from the specificated parent element